# Document Center best practice

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, records-management, document-center

Is it generally best practice to have a single Document Center for a company, with various Document libraries for different areas of the company, or create multiple Document Centers, perhaps by department?

Answer (score 1):

this will depend on the amount of data and members of your organization,

but as a best practice you'll want to create at least a site or site collection for each department and possible a subsite for each team on each department.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them can be deployed in this case , but before that ,you should compare and consider which scenario is suit for you .

## **Multiple Document Center :**

**Advantages** : Let each department manage and store their own files and policies , much safety .

**Disadvantage** :It very hard to manage for an Administrator .

## **Single Document Center** :

**Advantage :**

1. Only 1 site to store all files and items , much easy to manage .
2. For End users , they also prefer going to 1 place to find all your company policies , It is like one-stop-shop!

**Disadvantage :** If your organization are very huge , different department have own policy and be treated as departmental confidential , it is not very safety .